# How to use hourly time period statistics in power bi？

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

There are many data which have date time column, like createTime :2022/05/07 00:25.

I will split a day 24 hours into 12 periods.
For example: period1 include 1:00~2:00, period2 incliude 2:00~4:00... period12 include 23:00 ~ 24:00.

I need summary the record count group by createTime in the 12 periods. for example if there is a record which createTime is 2022/05/07 00:25, the count of period1 should add 1.

May i know How to do it in Power BI? I need display it use Pie chart finally.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Create a calculated column using the [HOUR function in DAX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/hour-function-dax). Then use that calculated column the "Legend" field for a pie chart visual.

Comment: After user HOUR function, I get the number of hour,like 1,2,3,4.......24,but How to summary it by use 2 hours? like , 1,2 should count together.

Comment: You can add this calculated column: Group = ROUNDUP('Table'[Hour]/2,0)

Comment: I had use the scripts to generate time periods.                timePeriods = IF(AND(HOUR('record'[creatTime]) >= 0,HOUR('record'[creatTime]) < 0)  , "0To4",
 IF(AND(HOUR('record'[creatTime]) >= 4,HOUR('record'[creatTime]) < 8)  , "4to8",
IF(AND(HOUR('record'[creatTime]) >= 8,HOUR('record'[creatTime]) < 12)  , "8to12",
IF(AND(HOUR('record'[creatTime]) >= 12,HOUR('record'[creatTime]) < 16)  , "12to16" ,
IF(AND(HOUR('record'[creatTime]) >= 16,HOUR('record'[creatTime]) < 20)  , "16to20",
IF(AND(HOUR('record'[creatTime]) >= 20,HOUR('record'[creatTime]) < 23)  , "20to23" )
 )
)
 )
 )
 )

Comment: Another approach is to use Power BI grouping and binning feature which will allow you to assign each integer to a group. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-grouping-and-binning

Please accept the answer if it works for you.

Comment: Yes, it is work for me,but i can not mark it as answer, becuase i am new guy for stackover flow. I do not have 15 reputation. I am so sorry for that.